# Devise embedded object 'Unpermitted parameter' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, rubygems

I have the following controller for user update

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def update
        super
        UserMailer.send_mail_on_account_update(current_user).deliver
    end

    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :shipping_details) }
    end

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
        edit_user_registration_path(resource)
    end
end
```

My user model `embeds_many :shipping_details` and shipping details has some fields like city, state.

In my user update form, I have the nested attributes of shipping_details. But when i submit the form, I see the following -

```
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/baDj9ThSRdF80inrxzM2G3sTtCXYqxNpl4PgDLJczM=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"sharma", "email"=>"rohit@sharma.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "shipping_details"=>{"address"=>"jldf", "city"=>"test"}}, "commit"=>"Update Details"} 
Unpermitted parameters: shipping_details
```

How do i make it permit the shipping_details field? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The way you've provided `:shipping_details` means for it to expect a simple string value, you're then passing in a hash. You should do this in your permit instead:

```
:shipping_details => { :address, :city }
```

Comment: What if i want shipping details to be an array of hashes (since a user can have multiple shipping details). I did u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, shipping_details: [ :address, :city ]) and I got 'undefined method `with_indifferent_access''